# Multiple Conditions while finding a web element in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

the inspect element Code looks as below :

```
*<*th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" data-field="Status" data-index="8" data-title="Status" scope="col" style="overflow: visible; white-space: normal;font-weight: bold;width:70px;vertical-align:top;" data-role="columnsorter" id="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell" aria-describedby="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell">
    <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
    <*span class="k-icon k-filter">
         </span></a><*a class="k-link" href="/tracs/tracs/LaborOps/AutoLaborOps_Read?grdAutoLaborOps-sort=Status-asc" tabindex="-1">Status</a>
</th>
```

There is a filter icon on the 10 th column of the grid ,I wanted to click that filter icon , if i used code as below

```
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("th.k-header.k-filterable.k-with-icon[data-title=Status]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class*='k-icon k-filter']")).click();
```

the first line code is clicking on 10th column which will set as ascending and descending order of 10th column.
the 2nd line code is clicking on the 1st column filter Icon .My Intension is to click on the 10th column filter icon

please Help

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Please paste your html dom. Then edit the question saying which element you want to  click

Comment: You are passing xpath to the css selector. IT will not work. and you will get the invalid selector exception.

Comment: Here is the Inspect Element Code

Comment: the inspect element Code <th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" data-field="Status" data-index="8" data-title="Status" scope="col" style="overflow: visible; white-space: normal;font-weight: bold;width:70px;vertical-align:top;" data-role="columnsorter" id="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell" aria-describedby="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell">
    <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
 <span class="k-icon k-filter">
         </span></a><a class="k-link" href="/tracs/tracs/LaborOps/AutoLaborOps_Read?grdAutoLaborOps-sort=Status-asc" tabindex="-1">Status</a>
</th>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to add **`@`** with the `attribute_name` **`data-title`** and instead of `cssSelector` it would be `xpath`. You can use either of the following options :

- **`cssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("th.k-header.k-filterable.k-with-icon[data-title=Status]")).click();
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[@class='k-header k-filterable k-with-icon' and @data-title='Status']")).click();
  ```

---

### Update :

If I have understood your question update well, the following line clicks on the `10th column, ascending and descending order`, which is perfecto.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("th.k-header.k-filterable.k-with-icon[data-title=Status]")).click();
```

So, to click on the `10th column filter icon` you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("th.k-header.k-filterable.k-with-icon[data-title=Status] span.k-icon.k-filter")).click();
```

Comment: change the By to xpath method. Or remove @ and // etc to make a css selector.

Comment: wanted to give multiple condition for <span class="k-icon k-filter">
         </span></a><a class="k-link" href="/tracs/tracs/LaborOps/AutoLaborOps_Read?grdAutoLaborOps-sort=Status-asc" tabindex="-1">Status</a>
</th>

Comment: @Akhil Update the question with your exact Manual step which you are trying to Automate along with the relevant HTML.

Comment: this is not working                            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class*='k-icon k-filter' @title='Status']")).click();                                                                           throwing error as invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: @ DebanjanB ,There  is an filter icon on the 10 th column of the grid  ,I wanted to click that filter icon , if i used code "span[class*='k-icon k-filter' ,it is clicking on the icon of 1st column of the grid so i wanted to give a 2nd condition which will check for the name as Status .

Comment: @Akhil These xpaths aren't part of my Answer. Try to use the exact xpath which I have provided in my Answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB,When i used your code ,It is clicking on the column which will set as ascending and descending order .But it is not clicking on the filter Icon .It is like ,am almost there not clicking on correct filter  icon .

Comment: @Akhil My Answer was based on your css/xpath which you tried out. For an effective Answer you have to update your Question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB,i have updated my question as suggested .

Comment: @Akhil Check out my updated Answer and let me know the status.